# Is file optimization with requirejs for angular.js necessary?

Tags: optimization, angularjs, requirejs

I know many people use Backbone with requirejs and r.js to optimize their javascript so that the web app only downloads one js file.

I have seen people using require.js an angular.js together, but it seems more like hack than an actual solution.

I'd like to know if this is good practice for angular.js too. If it is, perhaps there is a better way to do this rather than using requirejs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look into [Yeoman](http://yeoman.io). Specifically the [generator-angular](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular) project. Yeoman will scaffold an angular project for you, and set you up with [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/). Grunt will handle your build process (the minification and file concatenation) so you end up with one script file and one stylesheet.

There's a [nice, readable guide to Generators](http://yeoman.io/generators.html) on Yeoman's site that should help you get started. It's focused on writing your own generator, but it's a good look at what the idea is behind a generator and what they actually do.